# Facebook Share button Sometimes not showing the right image

Tags: html, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, share

I'm working on the obituary section of a funeral home website. Users can click the SHARE button under the person's picture to post the link to Facebook.

[Obituary listings](http://www.preston-hanley.com/obits/index.cfm?pageID=8)

I have meta-tags for the page title and image, labeled like Facebook tells you to: `<meta property="og:title"...` and `<meta property="og:image"`.

The problem is, the title and image that show up when you click the share button don't always show like they're supposed to. Sometimes the photo and person's name are right, but sometimes Facebook just picks the site's header image instead of the photo, and the site's title instead of the person's name.

Does anybody know why it isn't working consistently?

Comment: What does the [Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object) say?

Comment: It correctly shows the og:title and og:image that I want it to use. In every case.

Comment: F.e. http://www.preston-hanley.com/obits/details.cfm?pageID=8&obitID=4452 has `og:image` set to `http://www.preston-hanley.com/obits/images/4452.` right now. That’s not a valid image, that URL only leads to a 404.

Comment: Good eye. Some of the entries do not have photos. I'm ignoring those for now.

Comment: But, again, the ones that DO have pictures are still having issues.  :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a Facebook cache issue, which there's nothing I can do about.

Comment: Indeed it is a facebook bug. It only happens to me if im logged out of facebook though. Almost 2 years since your post and this has not been since fixed.